# Home work on normal distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

Determine $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of a normal curve such that $50$% of the probability lies in the $[6,8]$.
I think the data given is insufficient but I am not sure since it appeared in one of my assignment, so is there a way to solve and if yes, kindly provide the clue?

Comment: Maybe there's more than one correct answer.

Comment: Is the question asking whether the "50% btn 6 and 8" is sufficient to determine the mu and sigma of a normal curve and, if so, what is the mu and sigma?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Could you solve the similar problem of determining the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a distribution that is *uniform* between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $50\%$ of its probability lies in the interval $[6,8]$? If so, perhaps the same method will work here. If you can't solve this similar problem, why not? What is the obstacle?

Comment: @AdamO: yes you got it right.

Comment: @whuber no I couldn't solve because I think data is insufficient and don't know where to start from, also cannot prove why is it insufficient? any insight would be helpful

Comment: Start by writing down a formula for the probability in terms of the parameters.

Comment: Or start by drawing a diagram of a normal probability density function and think about where the interval [6,8] can be such that it has 50% probability (remember that area under the pdf is probability).

Comment: If you show at least 2 different solutions to a problem, then you have shown the problem does not have a unique solution. That would be a constructive proof of non-uniqueness.

Comment: 10%  to 20% of things we were supposed to prove in homework or exam problems in some of my graduate classes were incorrect, and even the Professor didn't know which ones were wrong - sometimes students found errors in the Professor's solutions, and the Professor's claim was wrong.  On the other hand, the Professors often didn't try too hard to get it right - they sometimes just winged it and hoped for the best.

Comment: Is the problem "Determine a μ and σ ..." or "Determine the μ and σ ..." ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you ask for a *clue* towards a solution, here is one. Begin by writing

> Let us assume that $\mu = 7$. Then $6$ and $8$ are the first and third
>   **quartiles** of the distribution. Hence, $\sigma = \cdots $

where I leave it to you to fill in the details.

Then show that you get a different standard deviation if you choose
$\mu = 7.5$.

For extra credit, explain why there is no solution if you choose
$\mu \leq 6$ or $\mu \geq 8$.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint:

Area under a curve sketched by $f(x)$(and the $x$ axis) between two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ is given by: $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)dx$

I am assuming $f(x)$ for a normal distribution should be known to you.